# How to create a realtime application using react native?

Tags: react-native, real-time

I want to create a **real-time application** **( for e.g. a stock market app)** in react native.

Currently I don't know any other way other than to use setInterval(), I am fetching data from a third party API.

So is there any way or third party tool available which gives real time data without using setInterval from a REST source?

Comment: Check out Fire Base and Pusher API.

Comment: Is data change happening in the back-end or front-end in your case ?

Comment: You should consider using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to make your application realtime.

Comment: @Ron I am fetching data from third party api and I have to show it in front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to my problem is the below post.
https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/using-socket-io-in-react-redux-app-to-handle-real-time-data-c0e734297795

Comment: Hi, can I ask which APIs you are using to fetch stock data? (NSE).

Answer (score 2):

This link can help you -> https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-real-time-todo-app-with-react-native-19a1ce15b0b3

Streaming Data Updates
You might have noticed that the todos are displaying fine, except you’re unable to view updated todos without refreshing the app. In this final step, we’re going to fit that missing part of the puzzle.

In the previous section, we added an onAllData method for the ReactiveList component. The second parameter of onAllData receives streaming updates which we’re going to utilize to always keep the todos updated. Here’s how the updated onAllData method will look like in components/TodosContainer.js.

Comment: this can help, but I've found another solution which fits in the scenario